# Qt/C++ QTcpSocket causes memory leak, not sure why

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qtcpsocket

I am creating a simple(ish) telnet server and am now debugging with valgrind.  the code runs great, but valgrind complains about memory lost when the program terminates...and the culprit is the line where I create a new QTcpSocket:

```
void TelnetConnection::run()
{
    tcpSocketPtr = new QTcpSocket();  // ** remove this due to parent error
    if (!tcpSocketPtr->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        emit error(tcpSocketPtr->error());
        return;
    }
}
```

I tried passing 'this' to the QTcpSocket() but then the signal-slots I try to connect complain about being associated with a different parent.  Is this the problem?  A clue?  And...what would the answer be?

---

I delete/free the tcpsocketptr by assigning it a value of 0 as per below.  Is that right?

```
void TelnetConnection::clientDisconnected()
{
    tcpSocketPtr = 0; // ** Cure memory loss?
    TelnetConnection::s_clientCount--;
    Logger *log =  Logger::instance();
    log->record(Logger::Information,EVENTID_TELNET_DISCONNECTION,"Telnet client "+QString::number(m_clientNumber) +": Disconnecting");
    QThread::quit();  // Exit ths event loop for this thread
}
```

Comment: Where do you `delete` that `tcpSocketPtr` ?

Comment: I showed the code called when the client has disconnected...and where I hopefully free the memory allocated for the socket.   Is this correct?

Comment: You don't `delete` the memory zone pointed by `tcpSocketPtr` you simply clear the pointer (without doing anything to the memory zone and the `QTcpSocket` object!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every time you call "new" you MUST call "delete."  As the comments have suggested, you point the pointer to 0, but never call delete.

Edited to add a YT video of a good explanation of the concepts: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_749lj2yb8Y  Essentially you are never freeing the memory you request from the CPU, hence you memory leak.  A simple call to delete will solve this.

Comment: Wow - big wrong assumption on my part...I thought c++ had a heap manager that cleaned up after me.  I'll have to use delete.  Thanks.